# React usEffect firing when it shouldn't be

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, use-effect

I have a react component with a prop that is passed by a redux connect method. There is a useEffect linked specifically to that prop that is supposed to perform an async call when it changes. The problem is the useEffect fires any time I change the redux state anywhere else in that app, despite the prop I have the useEffect attached to not changing.

The useEffect method looks like this

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (userPhoneNumber) {
      myAsyncFunction()
        .then(() => {
          showData()
        })
    }
  }, [userPhoneNumber])
```

And the userPhoneNumber prop is passed via the react-redux `connect` method like so:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    userPhoneNumber: state.appState.userPhoneNumber
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent)
```

From what I understand this could be breaking in two potential places. for one, useEffect should not be firing if the `userPhoneNumber` prop doesn't change. Also, the mapStateToProps method is not returning a new value so it should not be triggering any sort of a rerender.

The redux state changes that are leading to the unexpected useEffect call are coming from sibling components that have a similar react-redux connect setup to this component, with different state to prop mappings.

Comment: Is userPhoneNumber a string or object?

Comment: When a reducer runs you'll have an entirely new state object, thus a new `userPhoneNumber` prop reference. You should memoize the `userPhoneNumber` value. I use [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) to create memoized state selectors, but you could probably use the `useMemo` hook and use *that* memoized value in the dependency for the effect.

Comment: @DrewReese Even though redux creates a new state object with every object, it is only a shallow copy, with only the node that is changed by the reducer is a new object. All other nodes will be the same object. So unless the dispatch action is not changing `userPhoneNumber `  `oldState.userPhoneNumber === newState.userPhoneNumber`

Comment: @SubinSebastian `mapStateToProps` is returning a new object. https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect#motivation-for-memoized-selectors

Comment: `Also, the mapStateToProps method is not returning a new value so it should not be triggering any sort of a rerender` Every React component will re-render if its parent re-renders unless it is a `Pure Component`.  To make a functional component Pure, you have to wrap it with `React.memo`

Comment: @DrewReese As the link says Reselect is useful if you are doing very complex time-consuming computation on the state tree. But the prop that is passed to the component `userPhoneNumber` will be the same reference unless, the redux action caused reducer to alter userPhoneNumber part of the state tree. I will try to find a write up about it.

Comment: @NickMcCurdy userPhoneNumber is a string

Answer (score 0):

When a reducer runs you'll have an entirely new state object, thus a new `userPhoneNumber` prop reference. You should memoize the `userPhoneNumber` value. I use [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) to create memoized state selectors, but you could probably use the `useMemo` hook and use *that* memoized value in the dependency for the effect.

```
const memoizedUserPhoneNumber = useMemo(() => userPhoneNumber, [userPhoneNumber]);

useEffect(() => {
  if (memoizedUserPhoneNumber) {
    myAsyncFunction()
      .then(() => {
        showData()
      })
  }
}, [memoizedUserPhoneNumber]);
```

Using Reselect

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

const appState = state => state.appState || {};

const userPhoneNumber = createSelector(
  appState,
  appState => appState.userPhoneNumber;
);

...

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    userPhoneNumber: userPhoneNumber(state),
  }
}
```

None of this helps keep the entire functional component from re-rendering when the parent re-renders though, so to help with this you'll need to help "memoize" the props being fed into the component with the [`memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) HOC.

```
export default memo(connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent))
```

Comment: I tried both examples but unfortunately the same issue persists.

Comment: Have you done any logging to ensure that `userPhoneNumber` isn't actually being mutated or updated in state?

Comment: yes, it is the same string every time the useEffect is called. Even when I pass `[]` as the second argument to useEffect, which should make it only fire only the initial load, it will fire every time the redux state changes

Comment: It’s a string, it can’t be mutated and it’s only compared by value